# Using Built in Icons for Extension menus

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to reuse the "play" button icon used in the debugger toolbar for a new menu item I'm adding from an extension.

Is there a way to set up the icon information in "package.json" to use that existing svg already in VSCode or do I have to supply my own for extensions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using default VS Code icons on an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256809/using-default-vs-code-icons-on-an-extension)

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can use built-in icons, they are called Codicons.

Here is a list of them:
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels

To use them in your package.json, you will put `"icon": "$(iconIdentifier)"`.

Notice they will **not** work like this:

```
"icon":
{
    "light": "$(iconIdentifier)",
    "dark": "$(iconIdentifier)"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use build-in icons (codiconst) without need of installing anything. Just use $() to wrap icon name.

```
{
    "command": "whatever",
    "icon": "$(run-all)"
}
```