# Using default VS Code icons on an extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am making a VS Code extension for outlining TypeScript code structure. I am wondering how can I use the same icons VS Code uses in intellisense in my custom tree view:

[image]

Comment: Here is an answer I posted on a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65329535/1770034

Comment: @Questionable This does not answer the question, which asks for file icons. Apparently, as of today codicons can only be product icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to reference built-in icons, so you would have to include copies of these in your extension. This is [what the `vscode-code-outline` extension does](https://github.com/patrys/vscode-code-outline/tree/master/resources) (along with many others). There's a relevant feature request here:

[[icons] Support to allow re-using VSCode icons in user extensions (#31466)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31466)

There's a nice overview of all built-in document symbol / suggest icons [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2628#issuecomment-297566399). The `.svg` assets can be found here:

- [suggest](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/6511d05ec8f680d2fde87b4b5a1d909f78120697/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/media)
- [documentSymbols](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/tree/master/src/vs/editor/contrib/documentSymbols/media)

Answer (score 5):

### Update 2022:

It is now possible to use codicons in a tree item:

```js
getChildren() {
    return [
        {
            collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None,
            label: 'label',
            // Replace 'circle-outline' with desired codicon: https://microsoft.github.io/vscode-codicons/dist/codicon.html
            iconPath: new vscode.ThemeIcon('circle-outline'),
        }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use an available icon for a file that the icon same as what you see in the Explorer view, **it's possible**.

This is an example

```
getTreeItem(element: string): vscode.TreeItem | Thenable<vscode.TreeItem> {
  let treeItem = new vscode.TreeItem("MyFile.graphql", vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState.None);
  let filePath = path.join(this.currentDirectory, "MyFile.graphql");
  let fileUri = vscode.Uri.file(filePath);

  // set the file uri, and expected icon will appear
  treeItem.resourceUri = fileUri;
  return treeItem;
}
```

Just make sure the file is available and file uri is correct.