# Is it possible to change the icon that indicates whether a View Pane is collapsed or expanded in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, package.json

I am creating an extension for VS Code and i am trying to change the icon displayed near the tree view.

I have seen [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels) documentation but it is not very detailed.

I have also tried to do what is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403009/using-built-in-icons-for-extension-menus) post but it has not worked for me. There you have the code of my package.json:

```
 "views": {
      "my-sidebar": [
        {
          "id": "my-history-tree",
          "name": "History",
          "contextualTitle": "History",
          "type": "tree",
          "icon": "$(briefcase)"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I've also looked at some examples that vscode provides, but couldn't find any. I only found [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/tree-view-sample/package.json) one that uses an SVG directly.

So how can I use vscode's built-in icons without having to install any dependencies?

This is the icon i wanted to change:
[image]

Comment: How exactly do you want to use that icon?  In my testing, I wasn't able to use one of the product icons there, but the svg worked.

Comment: i just want to change the arrow icon and also understand why when i set the icon in the package.json nothing happens.

Comment: can you show a screenshot of what you want to change? It's not quite clear to me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vscode documentation is grossly incomplete. Apparently the "icon" configuration that is in the views of the "views" section is not to change the icon. But if you drag the view to another place (such as the activity bar) where the title cannot be displayed, then that icon is displayed. But the icon that appears next to the view, cannot be changed.

Comment: It still isn't clear what you mean by "the icon that appears next to the view"?  A picture is worth a 10000 words.

Comment: @Mark they updated their question post with an image and I edited the terminology of the question to use the correct terms. I think some of the answers posts here might have been misled.

Comment: @starball Yes, everyone was thrown off by the code in the question which has nothing to do with the expand/collapse icon.  But perhaps someone will learn something from the other answers as it isn't immediately clear from intellisense that you can use octicons.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use octicons as icons for Activity Bars and/or Views. Instead, you must use image files, and SVGs are the suggested format.

If you hover the `icon` property in the `package.json` file, you will see this hint:

> Path to the view icon. View icons are displayed when the name of the view cannot be shown. It is recommended that icons be in SVG, though any image file type is accepted.

A similar hint is displayed when you hover the `icon` message for the `activityBar`:

> Path to the container icon. Icons are 24x24 centered on a 50x40 block and have a fill color of 'rgb(215, 218, 224)' or '#d7dae0'. It is recommended that icons be in SVG, though any image file type is accepted.

Hope this helps

Comment: In fact, you can use the codicons for the views. In the example shown above it works. You just can't see it until you move the view and drop it in a place like the activity bar. If you do that, you will be able to see the icon.

Comment: If that´s the case, I suggest you to report an issue in VS Code repo, so the team can fix it.

Comment: And also update not only the documentation, but the hints provided by Intellisense while working with `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the documentation is not good.  You can also use codicons in `viewContainers` in addition to in `views`.   Those for a viewContainer are there immediately while those for a view only appear when dragging that view to the ActivityBar.

See [Test contributing codicons for views and view containers](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/111531).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the answer is no- you can't change this. If you open the devtools with the `Developer: Toggle Developer Tools` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and then inspect a View Panel's expanded/collapsed indicator (the icon that you're trying to change), you'll see something like `<div class="codicon codicon-view-pane-container-expanded">...</div>` or `<div class="codicon codicon-view-pane-container-collapsed"></div>` depending on whether it's expanded or collapsed.

- Then [search for `view-pane-container` in the source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode%20%22view-pane-container%22&type=code), where you'll see

  > ```js
  > const viewPaneContainerExpandedIcon = registerIcon('view-pane-container-expanded', Codicon.chevronDown, nls.localize('viewPaneContainerExpandedIcon', 'Icon for an expanded view pane container.'));
  > const viewPaneContainerCollapsedIcon = registerIcon('view-pane-container-collapsed', Codicon.chevronRight, nls.localize('viewPaneContainerCollapsedIcon', 'Icon for a collapsed view pane container.'));
  > ```
- Then [search for `viewPaneContainerExpandedIcon` in the source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode%20%22viewPaneContainerExpandedIcon%22&type=code) where you'll see

  > ```js
  > protected getTwistyIcon(expanded: boolean): ThemeIcon {
  >   return expanded ? viewPaneContainerExpandedIcon : viewPaneContainerCollapsedIcon;
  > }
  > ```
- Then [search for `getTwistyIcon` in the source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amicrosoft%2Fvscode%20%22getTwistyIcon%22&type=code) where you'll see this for initializing the header:

  > ```js
  >   protected renderHeader(container: HTMLElement): void {
  >     this.headerContainer = container;
  >
  >     this.twistiesContainer = append(container, $(ThemeIcon.asCSSSelector(this.getTwistyIcon(this.isExpanded()))));
  > ```

  And this for updating the UI on changes to the collapse/expand state:

  > ```js
  > override setExpanded(expanded: boolean): boolean {
  >   const changed = super.setExpanded(expanded);
  >   if (changed) {
  >     this._onDidChangeBodyVisibility.fire(expanded);
  >   }
  >   if (this.twistiesContainer) {
  >     this.twistiesContainer.classList.remove(...ThemeIcon.asClassNameArray(this.getTwistyIcon(!expanded)));
  >     this.twistiesContainer.classList.add(...ThemeIcon.asClassNameArray(this.getTwistyIcon(expanded)));
  >   }
  >   return changed;
  > }
  > ```

TL;DR it's hardcoded.